# CakePHP Testing, mocking AuthComponent

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I'm new at unit testing, and by that I mean I have **zero** knowledge of it. So naturally, I went and read a **bunch** of tutorials, guides, etc... and I understood a lot, but I'm still stucked on mocking `AuthComponent`. Here's my code (the comment lines indicates what I believe it does, feel free to correct me)

```
// The testing is generating a Controller
$Students = $this->generate('Student', array(
    'components' => array(
        'Auth' => array('user')
    )
));

$Students->Auth->expects($this->once())   // The testing is expecting to be called once
    ->method('user')                    // when calling $this->Auth->user();
    ->will($this->returnValue(array(    // return the following array
        'id' => 1,
        'role' => 'Administrator'
    )));

$Students->Auth->expects($this->once())   // The testing is expecting to be called once
    ->method('user')                    // when calling $this->Auth->user('id);
    ->with('id')                        // returns 1
    ->will($this->returnValue(array(1));
```

I'm not sure If i should write a block for each call of `$this->Auth->user($param)` or how should I do it, but I'm getting errors related to the parameter passed to `Auth->user()`,

My question would be, if my real code calls multiple times `Auth->user('id')`, what's the correct way of mocking it in a `ControllerTestCase` ?

Comment: You may be looking for the [**`at()` matcher**](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers), but it depends on the code you are testing...

Comment: I believe I'll understand it a little bit more if I could see an example (:

Comment: I've had a similar problem, but the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455540/mocking-an-authed-user-in-cakephp) did the trick for me.